# Is there a way to record the screen and encode the video later?

Tags: video, display, recording

Recording a screen can be quite computationally expensive. To alleviate the work that the CPU has to do, I was wondering if it was possible to encode after recording.

Comment: Uncompressed video files are _huge_. You'd probably rather want to use your GPU's video encoding capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Uncompressed video will use a huge amount of disk space and also disk write
operations.

You might lose performance by doing that, so it's not advisable.

Use a sophisticated screen-recording product and choose a video codec
that is supported by your GPU. A sophisticated recorder will have the
parameters for choosing a fast recording method.

One of the best screen recorders is
[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/),
but there are alternatives.

Comment: OBS is a popular free tool. I've also had good results with Mirillis Action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Some early recorders would save a static image for each frame and you could the process the frames afterward. But you end up with a lot of disk i/o since you have to save full frames instead of the compressed video. Computation can also be aided via your GPU if desired. I doubt you'd see any benefit recording the screen frame-by-frame. If you really want to save on live processing on your computer, consider an external recorder.